# How to ask how long will something continue in future?

Tags: future-tense, time, progressive-aspect

What is the appropriate way of asking question about how long an event will continue in future?

I want to ask, eg:

- How many *more days* will the product be in stock? *(incorrect?)*
- *How long* will the product last in stock ? *(incorrect? )*
- How many more days will this notice be kept on display? *(incorrect? )*

etc.

Please tell me the correct and natural way of asking these questions.

Comment: Where the answer may be known, as in all your examples, "will" is correct, but the second example could be written as, "How long **would** the product last in stock?", the subjunctive form, if the product were not in fact in stock when the question is raised.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik is using `How many more days` correct ? And no prepositions , eg `for`, is required ?

Comment: Both are correct, with and without a preposition. A preposition may be "understood", so "For how many days will it last?" and "How many days will it last?" are acceptable conversational English. See https://books.google.com/books?id=oNoNAQAAMAAJ&pg=PA181&lpg=PA181&dq=understood+preposition+%22how+long%22&source=bl&ots=ylhr0jSzl_&sig=yZ8RXrRIYKX22kdRb2LzCtKGaOs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=VLU2VaaPJMOwsASbuoDYCg&ved=0CCoQ6AEwAw#v=onepage&q=understood%20preposition%20%22how%20long%22&f=false, for example.

Comment: Answers entered as comments leave questions showing as 'unanswered'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As indicated in the comments, those are all perfectly correct.

Comment: is using *more* in those sentences considered correct ? as in *how many **more** days*?

Comment: That is correct.  The effect of more is to suggest or emphasize that what is continuing has already gone on for some time.  It can, depending on context, also suggest doubt as to remaining time.

Comment: Oh, but if something hasn't happened at all yet, it if it is just starting, then more would not make sense.  You have to already have something (in this case have days banked) before you can have more.